# c# Devexpress datagridview to gridcontrol. manualy

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, devexpress

```
if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From YazHata order by HataAdi ASC", connection);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            int sayac = 0;
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                sayac++;
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1);
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["gwSiraNo"].Value = sayac.ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Hataid"].Value = dt.Rows[i]["id"].ToString();

            }
            da.Dispose();
            connection.Close();


        }
```

How can I do it with devexpress as above? This

- dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1);
                     dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["gwSiraNo"].Value = sayac.ToString();
- dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Hataid"].Value = dt.Rows[i]["id"].ToString();
- dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["HataAdi"].Value = dt.Rows[i]["HataAdi"].ToString(); above.. Please help mee

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you please clarify it? What is _not working_ exactly? You get any exception or error message?

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't exist to do your work for you. Please read the [tour] and [ask] pages. Additionally, SO is an English-only site. There is an [Area 51 proposal for a Turkish Stack Overflow](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34945/stack-overflow-in-turkish) you might be interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the following code to make the ASPxGridView show data from this table:

```
if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed) {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From YazHata order by HataAdi ASC", connection);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            ASPxGridView1.DataSource = dt;  // <<<<
            ASPxGridView1.DataBind();  //<<<<<
            da.Dispose();
            connection.Close();
        }
```